# Showing that $E(X) = \int_{\Omega}X(\omega)d\mathbb{P}(\omega) = \int_\mathbb{R}xd\mathbb{P}_X(x)$

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$, so that X's expected value is $E(X) = \int_{\Omega}X(\omega)d\mathbb{P}(\omega)$. Suppose that $X$ has a law $\mathbb{P}_X$, so that $\mathbb{P}_X(A) = \mathbb{P}(X \in A)$. How could you then argue that $$E(X) = \int_\mathbb{R}xd\mathbb{P}_X(x).$$ The initial step is easy, as $$\int_\mathbb{R}xd\mathbb{P}_X(x) = \int_{x \in X[\Omega]}xd\mathbb{P}_X(x) = \int_{\Omega}X(\omega)d\mathbb{P}_X(X(\omega))$$ But I'm not entirely sure how to argue that $\mathbb{P}_X(X(\omega)) = \mathbb{P}(\omega)$. I've understood that the "no-brainer" approach is to show the claim for

1. for indicator functions,
2. non-negative simple functions,
3. non-negative measurable functions,
4. measurable functions

but I'd also like to understand the bigger picture of why we can swap the measures as we do.

**Edit:** In the event that someone still stumbles across this question, what I am really looking for is insight into the bigger picture, like  what @William M. suggested with the pushforward measure, and the literacy recommendation related to this same problem.

Comment: It is the change of variables formula: $\int f(x)d\mathbb P\circ X^{-1} (x)=\int f(X(\omega))d\mathbb P (\omega)$. You can varify it for simple functions first and then take limits.

Comment: Don't ask duplicate questions.

Comment: Check any measure theory book, it is one of the basic results, sometimes called "pushforward" or "change of measures."

Comment: @copper.hat My bad, I perhaps should have engaged in a discussion with Kavi Rama Murthy, or alternatively formulate my question better, since while his suggestion is correct, it doesn't help me to see the bigger picture. But in contrast that answer with the the pushforward and the book recommendation by William M. do help immensely.

Comment: You might add that information to the question?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for the suggestion and sorry for the late reply. I was just wondering that is the way to prove the claim to first consider $f$ to be a simple (indicator) function? Or should I view $X$ as an indicator r.v.?